# Excel: How to sum a column to date from a specified date where date ranges are involved

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm sure i have seen this done with a short formula but i am struggling to remember how to do it.

I am trying to find where a date falls in an interval and sum another column, from that point in the interval, to the end of all specified date intervals.

So, in the image below the intervals are in columns D and E and the date to find is in cell `F1` i.e. `12/12/2016`.

I want to find where `12/12/2016` falls within the ranges and sum column F accordingly i.e. `12/12/2016 - 13/12/2016` (2 days) and then all intervals after will be `2` + `6+2+1+3 = 14`. I am returning this result in cell `J14`.

[image: Data]

I have used the idea of histograms to calculate this currently, but the formula is large and unwieldy, and i just know i have seen a similar question, somewhere on SO but can't find it, that does this with `SUMPRODUCT` and `OFFSET` only. I guess `FREQUENCY` could also be used.

So what i have currently is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(F6,MATCH(TRUE,OFFSET(E6,0,0,COUNT(E6:E1048576),)>F1,0)-1,0,COUNTA(F6:F1048576),))-(F1-OFFSET(D6,MATCH(TRUE,OFFSET(E6,0,0,COUNT(E6:E1048576),)>F1,0)-1,,,))
```

Where, if i broke it down into stages, i find which bucket (range) has the target value:

`={MATCH(TRUE,OFFSET(E6,0,0,COUNT(E6:E1048576),)>F1,0)}`

I calculate the distance into the range with:

```
=F1-OFFSET(D6,H13-1,,,)
```

And i sum from this point until the end of the range with:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(F6,H13-1,0,COUNTA(F6:F1048576),))-I13
```

So, can anyone help me with a shorter more efficient formula please?

Data:

```
| Start of measurement | 12/12/2016 |                |
|----------------------|------------|----------------|
|                      |            |                |
|                      |            |                |
|                      |            |                |
| From                 | To         | Number of days |
| 13/11/2016           | 17/11/2016 | 5              |
| 10/12/2016           | 13/12/2016 | 4              |
| 03/02/2017           | 08/02/2017 | 6              |
| 06/12/2017           | 07/12/2017 | 2              |
| 09/12/2017           | 09/12/2017 | 1              |
| 12/12/2017           | 14/12/2017 | 3              |
```

Comment: `=SUMIF(E6:E11,">="&F1,F6:F11)-F1+INDEX(D6:D11,MATCH(F1,D6:D11))` adjust ranges to suit and format the result as General or Number

Comment: That is giving me a #NAME? error at present

Comment: Looks like there are hidden characters somehow from the comment.  Delete the final `D11` in the formula and retype it manually

Comment: @tigeravatar Correct. If you post as answer i will award to you as first to reply and upvote Alexis answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
=SUMIF(E6:E11,">="&F1,F6:F11)-F1+INDEX(D6:D11,MATCH(F1,D6:D11))
```

Comment: Can this be extended please with dynamic ranges so automatically updates for new ranges please?

Comment: Yes, that wouldn't cause any problems.  You can either use whole column references or define dynamic named ranges.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
=SUMIFS(F6:F11,D6:D11,">="&F1)+MINIFS(E6:E11,E6:E11,">="&F1)-F1+1
```

The `SUMIFS()` gives the `6+2+1+3` part and the `MINIFS() - F1 + 1` gives the `2` part.

---

Note that the `___IFS()` functions are more recent and not available in older versions of Excel.

Comment: Still get #Name with this despite typing in from scratch.

Comment: It is due to the MINIFS part which MS Office Professional Plus 2016 isn't given me any prompts for and doesn't seem to accept.

Comment: Should work for 2016 unless there are updates within 2016? I will have a go again tomorrow.

Comment: Now upvoted as have found the info re the build required. Apologies for the delay.